# An infinite path across the minefield

Tags: probability, recreational-mathematics

In $\mathbb{R}^2$, a mine is created at every integer point {$(z_1,z_2)\vert z_1,z_2\in \mathbb{Z}$} independently with probability $0\lt p\lt 1$. You choose a starting integer point, and can walk only along the integer lattice grid (up, down, left, right), without returning to previously walked path. What is the probability that there's a starting point from which you can safely walk on forever?

Comment: That's called "percolation threshold".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Elaborating on Ivan Neretin's comment, this particular model is known as [site percolation on the square lattice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percolation_threshold).

Let $q = 1-p$ be the probability that a vertex does not have a mine. Then it is known that there exists some $q_c \in (0,1)$ for which the probability of an infintely long 'safe path' is $0$ for all $q \leq q_c$ and $1$ for $q > q_c$.

The exact value of $q_c$ is an open question and is in general difficult to compute. It has been estimated to be $q_c \approx 0.5924...$

Comment: "the probability of an infintely long 'safe path' is $0$ for all $p \leq p_c$ and $1$ for $p > p_c$. "  Is this a typo? Should $p \leq p_c$ be $p \geq p_c$ or $p \gt p_c$?

Comment: @Eric It seems that the wiki page uses "occupation probability" p which means the probability that a node can be occupied by the percolating fluid, i.e. the probability of being initially empty. This is the opposite of how you used p.

Comment: @JaapScherphuis I see. Thanks!

Comment: @Eric: Jaap Scherphuis is correct; I had misread your question. I've edited it now to reflect this, and so in your notation the probability of an infinitely long safe path is $0$ for $p \gtrsim 0.4076...$ and $1$ otherwise.